# How do I prevent an unexpected disposal of Streams? (StreamReader, FileStream...)

Tags: c#, filestream, streamreader

I have some code where I'm trying to read a line within a Mainframe file before I download it from the host. I create an instance of the Stream class as an object called `reader`, retrieve the FTP data stream from the host and place it into the Stream object, and then create a copy of the original Stream object and its data into another Stream object called `readerCopy`. My issue, I think, is that when I pass `readerCopy` into a method that retrieves some data from the Stream(`RetrieveDateFromFile`), that the resources for both `readerCopy` and `reader` are disposed of after the method ends. So when my calling method tries to use `reader` later on it throws the following:

System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream''

I thought that encapsulating all of the Stream objects in `using` statements would make it so that the resources wouldn't be disposed of until the end of those statements are reached but it seems like they might be disposed of sooner.

What am I missing?

Calling method:

```cs
public void FtpFile()
{   
    // Gets the FTP data stream and stores it into reader, creates a new Stream object called readercopy.
    using (Stream reader = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream(), readerCopy = new MemoryStream())
    {
        if (reader != null)
        {
            reader.CopyTo(readerCopy);// Copies the original Stream to readerCopy.
            readerCopy.Position = 0;  //Sets the position to be beginning of the Stream.

            SMDPPITrigger trigger = new SMDPPITrigger(); //Custom class

            using (StreamReader fileReader = new StreamReader(readerCopy))
            {
                using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(ftpFileDestination, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    if (trigger.CheckIfExists(RetrieveDateFromFile(fileReader)) == false)
                        while (true)
                        {
                            bytesRead = reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length); //<--- error occurs here.

                            if (bytesRead == 0)
                                break;

                            fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Method to retrieve data from stream:

```cs
public DateTime RetrieveDateFromFile(StreamReader mainframeFile)
{
    string lineParsed = "";
    // StreamReader fileReader = new StreamReader(mainframeFile);

    for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
        switch (i)
        {
            case 2:
                string line = mainframeFile.ReadLine();
                if (line != null)
                {
                    lineParsed = line.Substring(124);
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }

            default:
            {
                mainframeFile.ReadLine();
                break;
            }
        }

    return DateTime.Parse(lineParsed);
}
```

Comment: I cannot see anything in your code that would Dispose `reader` before the end of the outer `using`, and calling a method - here even using `fileReader` which is not related to `reader` for sure will not dispose. But reader.CopyTo will set the position of `reader` to the end of the stream, so there is noting left to read.

Comment: Maybe RetrieveDateFromFile is disposing it since its passed as an arg. Try passing it as a reference.

Comment: @KlausGütter, I think that might actually be the issue and I misstated that `readerCopy` was being disposed of. I swapped out `reader` with `readerCopy`  on the line where the error was occurring and it ran fine. The error message throws me off especially if the original stream isn't actually closed but at the end of the stream since I've called `reader.CopyTo(readerCopy)`. I'll do some more testing to verify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing the loop on my question. It turns out the issue and resolution is exactly what @KlausGütter had said. Using `reader.CopyTo(readerCopy)` was setting my position to the end of the stream and my error message wasn't that it had been disposed but instead that there was nothing left to read. Using the stream that I copied over to, `readerCopy`, solved my issue since the stream is seekable.

Answer (score 0):

I am suspecting on below two lines of code causing problem.

```
reader.CopyTo(readerCopy);// Copies the original Stream to readerCopy.
readerCopy.Position = 0;  //Sets the position to be beginning of the Stream.
```

Can you try specifying length of stream you want to copy into readerCopy?
e.g

```
reader.CopyTo(readerCopy,124);
```